# Harmonic series with sign alternates every $n$ terms.

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, summation, oscillatory-integral

Let $A(1)=\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\dots$

Let $A(2)=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{8}+\dots$

Let $A(3)=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{9}-\frac{1}{10}-\frac{1}{11}-\frac{1}{12}+\dots$

In general, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$,  let $A(n)$ be the same series as the above with sign alternates every $n$ terms.

I know that $A(1)=\log(2)$, and $A(2)=\frac{1}{4}(\pi+\log(4))$.

How can we evaluate $A(n)$ for $n \in \mathbb{N_{\ge3}}$?

Comment: $A(1)$ is a well known sum , but please work out how you found $A(2)$

Comment: $A(3)$ seems to be about $1.4402486$  and $A(4)$ about $1.6767066$

Comment: One can also write $A(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\Phi \left(-1,1, \frac{k}{n}\right)}{n}$, where $\Phi$ is the Lerch transcendent.

Comment: This expression can be simplified to $A(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2n} \left(\psi \left(\frac{1}{2} +\frac{k}{2n}\right) - \psi \left( \frac{k}{2n}\right) \right)$, where $\psi$ is the digamma function. I'm not sure if there is any closed-form for this series, but regardless, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, this allows the computation of $A(n)$ to be trivial as values of $\psi$ at rational arguments are known.

Answer (score 2):

$A(3) = \lim_{m\to\infty} K_m$ where
$$
K_m = \sum_{k=1}^m\frac{1}{6k-5}
+\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{1}{6k-4}
+\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{1}{6k-3}
-\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{1}{6k-2}
-\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{1}{6k-1}
-\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{1}{6k}
$$
Then use estimates like
$$
\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{1}{6k-a} =
\frac{1}{6}\left(\log m-\psi\left(1-\frac{a}{6}\right)\right)+O(1/m)
$$
with the [Gauss digamma theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Gauss%27s_digamma_theorem) for $\psi$ of rational number.  Result:
$$
A(3) = \frac{\log 2}{3}+\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}} .
$$

Answer (score 2):

$A_n$ can be expressed as
$$
A_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{u=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^u}{nu+k}.
$$
Now, from the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{1+x}$ for $|x|<1$ we have
$$
{
\frac{1}{1+x}=\sum_{u=0}^\infty (-1)^ux^u\implies
\\
\frac{1}{1+x^n}=\sum_{u=0}^\infty (-1)^ux^{nu}\implies
\\
\frac{x^{k-1}}{1+x^n}=\sum_{u=0}^\infty (-1)^ux^{nu+k-1}\implies
\\
\int_0^1\frac{x^{k-1}}{1+x^n}dx=\sum_{u=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^u}{nu+k}
}
$$
hence
$$
A_n{=\sum_{k=1}^n \int_0^1\frac{x^{k-1}}{1+x^n}dx
\\=
\int_0^1\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x^{k-1}}{1+x^n}dx
\\=
\int_0^1\frac{1-x^n}{1+x^n}\frac{1}{1-x}dx
\\=
\int_0^1\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2u_k}{u_k-1}\frac{1}{x-u_k} dx
\\=
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2u_k}{u_k-1}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x-u_k} dx
\\=
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2u_k}{u_k-1}[\ln(1-u_k)-\ln(-u_k)]
}
$$
where $u_k=\exp(i\pi\frac{2k+1}{n})$ is the $k$th root of $-1$ and $\ln$ is the main branch of complex logarithm.

**Additional Remarks**

The reason for interchanging integrals and summations, is the existence and boundedness of the integral values and the boundedness of summation scope.